# Problema en recorrido con Foreach que me sustituye los anteriores valores

Tags: c#, array, lista, foreach, datagridview

Amigos tengo un sistema de Facturación aún en CFDI 3.3, estoy en Pagos 2.0 entonces estoy metiendo los Documentos Relacionados en un Grid, luego hago el siguiente foreach

```
List<PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado> lstDocRel = new List<PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado>();
PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado docRelacionado = new PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado();

                        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgDocRel.Rows)
                        {
                            docRelacionado.IdDocumento = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["uuid_"].Value);
                            docRelacionado.Folio = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["folio_"].Value);
                            docRelacionado.MonedaDR = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["moneda_"].Value);
                            docRelacionado.MetodoDePagoDR = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["metodo_"].Value);
                            docRelacionado.NumParcialidad = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["parcialidad_"].Value);
                            docRelacionado.ImpPagadoSpecified = true;
                            docRelacionado.ImpPagado = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["pagado_"].Value);
                            docRelacionado.ImpSaldoAntSpecified = true;
                            docRelacionado.ImpSaldoAnt = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["anterior_"].Value);
                            docRelacionado.ImpSaldoInsolutoSpecified = true;
                            docRelacionado.ImpSaldoInsoluto = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["insoluto_"].Value);

                            lstDocRel.Add(docRelacionado);
                            oPago.DoctoRelacionado = lstDocRel.ToArray();
                        }
```

Cuando se crea el XML e incluso cuando pongo un punto de interrupción para debug, me encuentro que si hace el recorrido el número de veces de las filas y con los valores bien, solo que si por ejemplo son 3 DocumentosRelacionados los 3 son el último, o sea el ultimo recorrido sustituye al anterior y por tal motivo tengo los 3 iguales, alguien sabe si tengo algún error en mi código?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes una única instancia de la clase `PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado` y esta en esta línea:

```
PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado docRelacionado = new PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado();
```

Como verás entonces todas las iteraciones del foreach actualizan la misma variable y la agregan a la lista varias veces.

Para tener valores diferentes debes instanciar la variable dentro del bucle lo que significa una nueva instancia de la clase cada vez.

Además pareciera que la última línea también debe salir del `foreach`

```csharp
List<PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado> lstDocRel = new List<PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgDocRel.Rows)
{
    PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado docRelacionado = new PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado();

    docRelacionado.IdDocumento = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["uuid_"].Value);
    docRelacionado.Folio = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["folio_"].Value);
    docRelacionado.MonedaDR = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["moneda_"].Value);
    docRelacionado.MetodoDePagoDR = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["metodo_"].Value);
    docRelacionado.NumParcialidad = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["parcialidad_"].Value);
    docRelacionado.ImpPagadoSpecified = true;
    docRelacionado.ImpPagado = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["pagado_"].Value);
    docRelacionado.ImpSaldoAntSpecified = true;
    docRelacionado.ImpSaldoAnt = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["anterior_"].Value);
    docRelacionado.ImpSaldoInsolutoSpecified = true;
    docRelacionado.ImpSaldoInsoluto = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["insoluto_"].Value);

    lstDocRel.Add(docRelacionado);
}

oPago.DoctoRelacionado = lstDocRel.ToArray();
```

O si me permites simplificar un poco el código para hacerlo menos verboso

```csharp
var lstDocRel = new List<PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado>();

foreach (var row in dgDocRel.Rows)
{
    var docRelacionado = new PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado
    {
        IdDocumento = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["uuid_"].Value),
        Folio = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["folio_"].Value),
        MonedaDR = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["moneda_"].Value),
        MetodoDePagoDR = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["metodo_"].Value),
        NumParcialidad = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["parcialidad_"].Value),
        ImpPagadoSpecified = true,
        ImpPagado = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["pagado_"].Value),
        ImpSaldoAntSpecified = true,
        ImpSaldoAnt = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["anterior_"].Value),
        ImpSaldoInsolutoSpecified = true,
        ImpSaldoInsoluto = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["insoluto_"].Value)
    };

    lstDocRel.Add(docRelacionado);
}

oPago.DoctoRelacionado = lstDocRel.ToArray();
```

Y ahora absolutamente todo puede ser simplificado a una única expresión utilizando `Select()`

```csharp
oPago.DoctoRelacionado = dgDocRel.Rows.Select(row => new PagosPagoDoctoRelacionado
{
    IdDocumento = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["uuid_"].Value),
    Folio = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["folio_"].Value),
    MonedaDR = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["moneda_"].Value),
    MetodoDePagoDR = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["metodo_"].Value),
    NumParcialidad = Convert.ToString(row.Cells["parcialidad_"].Value),
    ImpPagadoSpecified = true,
    ImpPagado = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["pagado_"].Value),
    ImpSaldoAntSpecified = true,
    ImpSaldoAnt = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["anterior_"].Value),
    ImpSaldoInsolutoSpecified = true,
    ImpSaldoInsoluto = Convert.ToDecimal(row.Cells["insoluto_"].Value)
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: muchas gracias no me habia dado cuenta, me solucionaste unas horas